# Recursive tree symmetry

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have written the following code snippet to determine if a Binary Tree is symmetrical or not:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    bool symmetricityChecker(TreeNode* root, int level) {
        bool isValid=false;

        if(root==NULL)
            return true;

        if(level==1)
            isValid = root->left->val==root->right->val;

        if(root->left!=NULL && root->right!=NULL) {
            if(root->left->left!=NULL && root->right->right!=NULL)
                isValid = root->left->left->val==root->right->right->val;

            if(root->left->right!=NULL && root->right->left!=NULL)
                isValid = root->left->right->val==root->right->left->val;
        }

        return isValid && symmetricityChecker(root->left, level+1) && symmetricityChecker(root->right, level+1);
    }

    bool isSymmetric(TreeNode* root) {
        return symmetricityChecker(root, 0);
    }
};
```

My aim is, at level 1, I check if the root's left and right children are equal (since at this level there is just a root and its two children).  For all the remaining levels, I check if the `left` child of the `root`'s `left` child is equal to the `right` child of the `root`'s `right` child.  Similarly, I check if the `right` child of the `root`'s `left` child is equal to the `left` child of the `root`'s `right` child.  (This is so, because the symmetry of the root's immediate left and right children has already been checked in the previous recursive call).

I believe that my algorithm is correct, but it is generating incorrect results.  Could someone kindly point out if my logic is incorrect, or are there errors in the implementation?

**Edit:**  I tested the code for the input `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3]`.  I expect the answer to be `true`, but get a `false` instead.  Hence I am not sure if I have a *logical* flaw in my approach.

Comment: What does your debugging show? For what binary trees have you tested?

Comment: @E_net4, I tested it for `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3]`.  I expect the answer to be `true`, but I get `false`.  Hence not sure if there is a _logical_ flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong part is where you're doing that:

```
    return isValid && symmetricityChecker(root->left, level+1) && symmetricityChecker(root->right, level+1);
```

By calling `symmetricityChecker` on a single child node, you're expecting the children to be symmetric as well, but this shouldn't be true. So it'll fail because the subtree [2,3,4] is not symmetric and consider the whole tree as not symmetric even if this is not true.

To check symmetry recursively, you have to keep two nodes (i.e. left and right) as your state, not just one. Once you confirm that the two nodes are symmetric, recursively check their children by a similar check to what you're doing above in the nested if conditions.

Another approach is to write a BFS, and check that all the nodes in the same level are symmetric. This way, it should be as easy as checking if an array is symmetric because you'll have all the nodes of the same level in the same array next to each other.

EDIT:
Adding a pseudocode:

```
bool symmetricityChecker(left, right) {
    // Write the base case, check for nulls, corner cases, etc.
    if(left != right) return false
    return symmetricityChecker(left.left, right.right) &&
           symmetricityChecker(left.right, right.left)
}
```

At the beginning when you only have the root, call this method with the root's children.

Comment: Got your point, thank you!  Also, I am not using a BFS since it would be an `O(nlogn)` operation - `log n` due to the height of the Binary Tree and `n` to check if the current level is a palindrome.  The current approach is `O(n)`.

Comment: Also, this means that my logic is correct, right?  I mean, checking the children of children from the current root?

Comment: It should be the same complexity. You're visiting each node the same number of times whether you're doing that breadth-first or depth-first. The thing is, ```n``` in each level is not the same ```n``` that refers to the total number of nodes. So it'll sum up to O(n) at last where n is the total number of nodes.

Comment: The main idea is close to the correct one and could be modified to be correct. I mean you don't need to rewrite the whole thing. If you feel stuck I can add a pseudocode to what I mean.

Comment: If you add pseudo code, that would really be very helpful.  I would exactly understand what I did wrong and learn a lot from it.  Thank you!